# Delete Files older then 180 days EXCEPT files in root path

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to be able to delete all files  (NOT FOLDERS) in subdirectories that are older then 180 days. The only catch is, I don't want to touch any files in the root path directory.

So If I have the path: S:\UserData\User1
                       S:\UserData\User2
                       S:\UserData\User3

I would like to delete the files older then 180 days in the User1,User2, and User 3 directorys. Any file in S:\UserData I would like to not be touched.

I've tried using FORFILES but there doesnt seem to be a command to exclude folders.

Thanks!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: As websch01ar was hinting at, if you have PS v3+ there is the -File switch for Get-ChildItem that will only return files, and will exclude folders from the file system provider's results. This is considerably faster than filtering in Powershell (such as `Where{!$_.PSIsContainer}`), but can have some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /SpSupersededTry this out:

```
[int] $AddDays = -180
$directories = gci -path "S:\UserData\" -directory
$directories | % {
        $files = gci -path $_.fullName -file -Recurse | ? { $_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays($AddDays) }
        $files | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf #Note that I added WhatIf here for testing!
    }
```

Comment: Yours is checking to make sure that it is created before 180 days in the future. Also, CreationDate is not a valid property, use CreationTime.

Comment: Ah...In my test case I have the -180, and then decided to create a variable to hold it and forgot the negative.  And fat-fingered the CreationTime as well.  I made the edits and now it will work as they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Get-ChildItem accepts wildcards as part of the path so you could use that to sort of declare the root folder and get what is below it. Then you can use where to skip directories

gci 'c:\dontexist\user*' -recurse | ? {-not $_.psiscontainer}

Obviously you would want to test this pretty thoroughly and make sure it is targetting the data you want before you do any delete actions. Don't forget most you can use -whatif parameter on remove-item to test as well when you get to that point.

Edit: An alternative answer that is less specific

```
gci 'c:\dontexist\*\*\' -recurse | ? {!$_.psiscontainer -and $_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)} | remove-item -whatif
```

Comment: Why am I downvoted? Lol, OP specifically said the following

"Any file in S:\UserData I would like to not be touched."

My code is much more effective than websch01ar and meets the OP's needs. It is also version compatible as the -directory switch was not available in earlier PS versions.

Comment: You were probably downvoted (wasn't me) because your solution is way too specific to be practical. What if they have User1, User2, User3, and Public folders? Your solution would ignore the Public folder.

Comment: I did ask about the version of PowerShell, and then gave the POSH 3.0 answer.

Comment: Fair enough on the comment about specificity. An alternative is below then that still uses the same wildcard method but isn't specific outside of excluding the root
`gci 'c:\dontexist\*\*\' -recurse`

Comment: Much better. Actually, update your answer to that and add in date checking and that (IMHO) is the best answer on the page.

Comment: Thanks, and for pointing out the specificity issue...made sense after.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple RegEx match against the FullName to make sure it has at least one folder between the file and the root drive. Toss in a `!$_.PSIsContainer` to make sure it's not a folder, and something to check the creation date to make sure it's old enough, and pipe it right to Remove-Item

```
$Path = "S:\UserData"
$Path = $Path.TrimEnd("\")
Get-ChildItem $path -recurse| Where{(!$_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.FullName -match "$([regex]::escape($path))\\.+?\\.+" -and $_.CreationDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)} | Remove-Item
```

**Edit:** Updated to work for non-root located "root" folders.

Comment: You can also use the -Directory switch on GCI to limit to just a directory.

Comment: I've run into enough people that have older PowerShell versions that I usually avoid that now in answers. As you were responding to my answer I was actually responding to the main post with something very similar, explaining about -file.

Comment: Works for me . . . ppl need to upgrade POSH imo.  I did wait nearly 20 mins before posting an answer in hope the OP would answer.

Comment: @websch01ar With the +/- date and property name corrections your answer is great, it'll work just fine for the OP's purpose. I'm not criticizing, just commenting. Um, you do need to either use `$dir` or `$directories` though. Aside from that, you have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this.

```
$strRootPath = "S:\UserData"
$intMaxFileAge = 180

Foreach ($objFolder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $strRootPath | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $true})) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $objFolder.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {
        If (((Get-Date)-($_.CreationTime)).TotalDays -gt $intMaxFileAge) {
           Remove-Item -Path $.FullName -Force
        }
    }
}
```